# Javascript "Silly Name Generator"

Tags: javascript

I took a JavaScript class semester before last, passed it, and now 
    I'm on summer   break. The book we used is JavaScript 8th edition, Tom Negrino,
    Dori Smith. There is code for a name generator. Everything needed is in the book
    (p. 301) It calls for a first and last name but I wanted to add a middle name 
    to output another silly name. It's not a homework assignment, just something
    I wanted to try. If you leave the first or last name blank you get a "That's
   not a valid name" message. So I coded the middle name, entered 26 words for
   the middle name, but the code doesn't recognize anything other than first
   and last name. To me it looks like this should work but still only first
   and last name work. Maybe another pair of eyes could help me see what
   I've missed or not included.

Thanks for any suggestions, CK

```
The HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Silly Name Generator</title>
<script src="script05.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>What's your silly name?</h1>
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="rtAlign">First Name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="fName" size="30"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="rtAlign">Middle Name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="mName" size="30"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="rtAlign">Last Name:</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="lName" size="30"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" id="sillySubmit">
</tr>
</table>
<p id="msgField">&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

---

The JavaScript

```
window.onload = initAll;

function initAll() {
document.getElementById("sillySubmit").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("msgField").innerHTML = getSillyName();
    return false;
}
}

function getSillyName() {
var firstName = ["Runny", "Buttercup", "Dinky", "Stinky", "Crusty",
"Greasy","Gidget", "Cheesypoof", "Lumpy", "Wacky", "Tiny", "Flunky",
"Fluffy", "Zippy", "Doofus", "Gobsmacked", "Slimy", "Grimy", "Salamander",
"Oily", "Burrito", "Bumpy", "Loopy", "Snotty", "Irving", "Egbert"];

var middleName =["Waffer", "Lilly","Rugrat","Sand", "Fuzzy","Kitty",
 "Puppy", "Snuggles","Rubber", "Stinky", "Lulu", "Lala", "Sparkle", "Glitter",
 "Silver", "Golden", "Rainbow", "Cloud", "Rain", "Stormy", "Wink", "Sugar",
 "Twinkle", "Star", "Halo", "Angel"];

var lastName1 = ["Snicker", "Buffalo", "Gross", "Bubble", "Sheep",
 "Corset", "Toilet", "Lizard", "Waffle", "Kumquat", "Burger", "Chimp", "Liver",
 "Gorilla", "Rhino", "Emu", "Pizza", "Toad", "Gerbil", "Pickle", "Tofu", 
"Chicken", "Potato", "Hamster", "Lemur", "Vermin"];
var lastName2 = ["face", "dip", "nose", "brain", "head", "breath", 
"pants", "shorts", "lips", "mouth", "muffin", "butt", "bottom", "elbow", 
"honker", "toes", "buns", "spew", "kisser", "fanny", "squirt", "chunks", 
"brains", "wit", "juice", "shower"];

var firstNm = document.getElementById("fName").value.toUpperCase();
var middleNm = document.getElementById("mName").value.toUpperCase();
var lastNm = document.getElementById("lName").value.toUpperCase();
var validName = true;

if (firstNm == "") {
    validName = false;
}
else {
    var firstNum = firstNm.charCodeAt(0) - 65;

    if (firstNum < 0 || firstNum > 25) {
        validName = false;
    }
}

if (!validName) {
    document.getElementById("fName").focus();
    document.getElementById("fName").select();
    return "That's not a valid first name";
}
if (middleNm == "") {
    validName = false;
}
else {
    var middleNum = middleNm.charCodeAt(0) - 65;

    if (middleNum < 0 || middleNum > 25) {
        validName = false;
    }
}
if (!validName) {
    document.getElementById("mName").focus();
    document.getElementById("mName").select();
    return "That's not a valid middle name";
}

if (lastNm == "") {
    validName = false;
}
else {
    var lastNum1 = lastNm.charCodeAt(0) - 65;
    var lastNum2 = lastNm.charCodeAt((lastNm.length-1)) - 65;

    if (lastNum1 < 0 || lastNum1 > 25 || lastNum2 < 0 || lastNum2 > 25) {
        validName = false;
    }
}

if (!validName) {
    document.getElementById("lName").focus();
    document.getElementById("lName").select();
    return "That's not a valid last name";
}

return "Your silly name is " + firstName[firstNum]
 + " " +  middleName[middleNum] + " " + lastName1[lastNum1]
 + lastName2[lastNum2];
 }
```

Comment: Why in the world all this code instead of 3 simple random calls...

Comment: it looks fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yfATj/2/

Comment: @Blindy I suppose for the sake of learning *left as an exercise for the reader to complete*

Comment: @Blindy, maybe I'm misunderstanding but returning random entries in the list would mean that a person's silly name would change every time they used the generator. Persistence is a good feature in a name. :)

Comment: @mmitchell, not necessarily true, you can seed the generator with something like the characters in the name xor'd together. Perlin noise comes to mind straight away.

Comment: @Blindy, you cannot seed Math.random() in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML and JavaScript is working for me. My guess would be that your browser is caching your old JavaScript file.  Try clearing your browser's cache or refreshing without cache (usually ctrl-f5 or shift-f5).